# Spectral norm of block and square matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values, spectral-radius

I am struggling with a problem for the past few days and I would really appreciate someone's help.
The problem is the following:

> If $A$ is a square $n×n$ matrix, prove that the matrix
>   $$B=\begin{bmatrix}A^*&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}$$
>   has the same spectral norm (2-norm) as matrix $A$.

I managed to prove that the eigenvalues of all 4 matrices $(A,A^*,B,B^*)$ are the same, but I am not sure that it means the spectral norm is also the same. Sorry for poor post quality, it is my first time here.

Comment: The spectral norm is also the largest singular value.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the response. Yes, I realize it is also the largest singular value; however, it is still not helping me with the proof. Or am I maybe looking at it the wrong way?